# Firebase Cloud Functions: Deployed onCreate function not triggering consistently

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been using firebase cloud functions for a few months now as a solution for a CRM application.

I have many `onCreate` trigger functions on various collections in firestore.

In my application, I occasionally use a `transaction` to create multiple copies of documents all in the same collection. I would expect it to trigger the `onCreate` function X times if X documents are created, but more often than not the number is less than X.

This bug has occurred plenty of times, across various different collections that all execute a different function on create, and I am not able to identify any bugs with my code. Even a simple `onCreate` that logs to the console when it's called doesn't get reliably triggered.

Comment: Hello, without the **entire** code it will be very difficult to help you. Cloud Functions may have erratic behaviour/result if their life cycle is not correctly managed.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Hi, thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I am not able to reveal the entire codebase of 3000+ lines. Where can I go to for documentation on cloud function lifecycles?

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions